# Rails appending string in CSS file name

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

I don't know why is it happening, Rails4 is changing my CSS file name. What I remember that in config I added `config.assets.digest = true` but now I commented it. If that's the reason then how do I revert it. The file which was named as `style.css` Chrome shows as `style-09c2ffa55593d359fe6e2a46b0f118eb.css?body=1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`config.assets.digest` default to `true`, so if you commented it out it is still set to `true`. add to your application.rb `config.assets.digest = false` then restart your server and finally do a hard refresh in your browser with SHIFT+F5